# Understanding sed -i '/Keep Error Fields/d'

Tags: unix, sed

I am looking over some bash scripts written by someone who used to work at my company, and am trying to understand the following sed command:

```
LOG_DIR=/somelocation
ERROR_LOG="batch_errors_"$*".log"

# remove any non genuine error fields
sed -i '/Keep Error Fields/d' $LOG_DIR/$ERROR_LOG
if [ -s $LOG_DIR/$ERROR_LOG ]
then 
 #DO SOMETHING
fi
```

The intention of the script to is look through a list of log files, and add to the ERROR_LOG any times where there is the word ERROR is found in any of the logs. I believe the above is intended to remove any of these entries that are not the result of a "genuine" error.

I don't understand what `'/Keep Error Fields/d'` is doing or how it is identifying these errors as non-genuine. Is this something built into the sed command?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: `'/Keep Error Fields/d'` means delete lines matching that particular search string... you can find more related examples here on [sed doc](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range#t=201704031448441117151)

Comment: Okay - great, I thought it was doing something a little more sophisticated!

Comment: @Sundeep Please make an answer, I want this out of the list "answers:0".

Comment: @Yunnosch you can make an answer too if you wish :) imo this question should be deleted by OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'/Keep Error Fields/d'` means delete lines matching that particular search string...

Quoting Sundeep to make a nice Q/A pair, with his permission.